# The exception occurs when I try to use Nuxt3 to add the nitro plugin

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt3, nitro

(My English is weak, the following text is translated by Deepl)
In the process of learning this framework by reading the Nuxt3 documentation, when I read the following section

https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/views#advanced-extending-the-html-template

I encountered a problem in the code practice, I created the following file '~/server/plugins/extend-html.ts'

```
import {nitroApp} from "nitropack/dist/runtime/app";


export default defineNitroPlugin((nitro) => {
    nitroApp.hooks.hook('render:html',(html,{ event }) => {
        console.log(html)
        console.log(event)
        html.head.push('<meta name="test" content="test">')
    })

    nitroApp.hooks.hook('render:response',(response,{ event }) => {
        console.log(response)
    })
})
```

and added in nuxt.config.ts as per the documentation.

```
  nitro:{
    plugins:[
        '~/server/plugins/extend-html.ts',
    ]
  }
```

But there is an error

```
[17:11:34]  ERROR  [worker reload] [worker init] Package import specifier "#internal/nitro/virtual/plugins" is not defined in package D:\\WebStormProject\\Nuxt-test\\node_modules\\nitropack\\package.json imported from D:\\WebStormProj
ect\\Nuxt-test\\node_modules\\nitropack\\dist\\runtime\\app.mjs

at __node_internal_captureLargerStackTrace (node:internal/errors:490:5)
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
at importNotDefined (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:350:10)
at packageImportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:777:9)
at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:932:16)
at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1153:11)
at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:838:30)
at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)
at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36)
```

I have tried the following for this bug

1. > Delete node_modelus to rebuild the project ×
2. > Update nitropack to the latest version ×
3. > Restarting the project ×

I hope you can give me some help, thanks a million!
(tip:When I remove extend-html.ts and its related content in the project, the project works fine

Comment: It looks weird you have'.ts' and no typescript inside. Have you properly set up typescript? Did you try to change it to '.js' or '.mjs'?

Comment: I tried changing the suffix of extend-html to js/mjs
But the error message didn't change